# What are the files with the ".O" extension in `/etc/cups/ppd` used for?

Tags: drivers, printing, cups-lpd

I would like to know what the duplicate files in `/etc/cups/ppd` with .O suffixed mean and what they are used for (opposed to the ones without suffix). For example:

```
$ ls /etc/cups/ppd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root lp  9912 Jan  5 12:56 prt1.ppd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root lp  9878 Jan  5 12:51 prt1.ppd.O
-rw-r--r--. 1 root lp  1311 Jan  6 15:21 prt2.ppd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root lp  1311 Jan  6 15:24 prt2.ppd.O
```

Comment: There is a similar question on Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2123691

Comment: ... and on U&L: [Why are there .O files in /etc/cups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471104/why-are-there-o-files-in-etc-cups)

Comment: Ask your system?   Ubuntu and any GNU/Linux or unix system use the contents of files (not part of the name [extension]) to dictate what type of file it is.  `file prt1.ppd.O` should tell you what they contain.  The actual '.o' means nothing except it's part of the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.O` files are created by the CUPS system whenever the printer configuration is changed, e.g., if `/etc/cups/printers.conf` is modified, the previous version is automatically saved as `/etc/cups/printers.conf.O`. This makes it easy to revert to a previously working configuration.

According to [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471110/22812) the

> `.O` stands for `oldfile` as indicated in `cups/scheduler/file.c`:
>
> ```
> oldfile[1024];            /* filename.O */
> ```